# Incompatible pointer to integer sending 'UITextField*

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, warnings

I have an issue with UITextField

I want user enter the date to run notification and I use this in .m

```
  [dateComponent setWeekday:1]; // For sunday
  [dateComponent setHour:timeHClass];
  [dateComponent setMinute:timeMClass];
```

and this in .h

```
  @property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *timeHClass;
  @property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *timeMClass;
```

but it shows me this warning:

`incompatible pointer to integer sending 'UiTextField*__strong' to parameter of type 'NSInteger' (aka 'long')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be doing:

```
[dateComponent setHour:[timeHClass.text integerValue]];
[dateComponent setMinute:[timeMClass.text integerValue]];
```

You want to get the text typed in the field and use it with your date component.

Explanation: `timeHClass` object is an `UITextField` so you want to access the `text` property of it, which is an `NSString` object, and convert it to an `NSInteger` value. You should also make sure that your text field is numeric.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the UITextField properties of your class as the hour and minute components. These fields call for integers, just like you did with `[dateComponent setWeekday:1];`.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to send a pointer to an `UITextField *` object as a parameter which should be NSInteger instead. Try:

```
[dateComponent setHour:[timeHClass.text integerValue]];
```

But be really careful with this type of conversion, user might type in something you don't want. You'll have to check the input text beforehand to avoid unpredictable behaviour.

Comment: yeah i make user just enter numbers but how could i make him enter number between 0-23 for hours and 0-59 for min

Answer (score 0):

You have to take the content of your text field, not your textfield itself:

```
[dateComponent setWeekday:1]; // For sunday
[dateComponent setHour:[timeHClass.text integerValue]];
[dateComponent setMinute:[timeMClass.text integerValue];
```